# Empty Kendo-Editor from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

I am using kendo ui richtextbox on one of my pages:

```
<textarea kendo-editor rows="3" cols="4" ng-model="fooData.Answer" id="answerInput" placeholder="blablablabla" class="form-control" k-encoded="false"></textarea>
```

In my controller I have:

```
function ($scope, $sce, Foo) {
    $scope.foos = [];
    $scope.fooData = kendo.observable();


    $scope.addFoo = function (fooData) {
        Foo.create(fooData)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.fooData = kendo.observable();
                $scope.foos.push(data);
            });
    }
```

Which adds an item foo to a collection using an api, which all works like a charm. The thing that does not work is that the kendo-editor does not get emptied. The input remains. In the documentation they stated that you should use kendo.observables, which I do, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparetnly I just needed to do

```
$scope.fooData.Answer = "";
$scope.fooData.Question = "";
```

in my addFoo function.